# Ordenar objeto alfabeticamente em React/Gatsby

Tags: javascript, react, classificação

Boa tarde.

Eu tenho uma [API](https://john-strapi.herokuapp.com/b) em Strapi rodando no Heroku renderizada nesse [site](https://punkcore.com.br) em Gatsby. Minha pergunta é: como poderia colocar as bandas em ordem alfabética? Por minhas pesquisas, teria que ser **sort()** no **useEffect**. Mas como? Já tentei de tantas formas que nem lembro mais...

Esse é meu useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  const loadBands = async () => {
   const response = await api.get();
   setBands(response.data);
   setLoading(false);
 };

 loadBands();
```

}, []);

E minha renderização está assim:

```
{bands
      .filter(val => {
        if (searchBand == "") {
          return val;
        } else if (
          val.band_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchBand.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          return val;
        }
      })

      .map(band => (
        <article className="bands" key={band.id}>
          <h2>{band.band_name}</h2>
          <img
            src={band.band_img.formats.thumbnail.url}
            alt={band.band_name}
          />
          {console.log(band.band_img)}
          <p>{band.band_desc}</p>
          <div className="btns">
            <iframe
              src={`https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/${band.band_site}`}
              width="50%"
              height="80"
              frameBorder="0"
              allowtransparency="true"
              allow="encrypted-media"
            />
            <a href={band.youtube} target="_blank">
              <button>youtube</button>
            </a>
            <a href={band.wikipedia} target="_blank">
              <button>wikipedia</button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </article>
      ))}
```

Aqui está o [repositório](https://github.com/jcgsr/ago-JohnPunkBandsList) no Github se servir de algo para poderem me ajudar.

Desde já, muito grato pela paciência.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
let bands = response.data;
bands.sort((a,b) => (a.band_name.toLowerCase() > b.band_name.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : ((b.band_name.toLowerCase() > a.band_name.toLowerCase()) ? -1 : 0));
setBands(bands);
```

Comment: Perfeito!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou! Tô fazendo o build aqui. Vc poderia me explicar a lógica se não for muito incômodo, claro.